# Jekyll blog error: Could not locate the included file 'file.ext' in any "_includes"

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm a newbie to use jekyll as github blog page creater. now i try to write a md file under _posts folder, i copy the text and layout from [Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/), [image] due to it contains some Liquid syntax(showed above).
When i run Jekyll in local, the below error is showed.

```html
Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'file.ext' in any of
 ["C:/Developments/GitRepository/testRepository/blogFork1/_includes"]. 
Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, 
does not point outside your site source. 
in C:/Developments/blogFork1/_posts/2018-08-03-first-blog.md
```

What i write in md file: 
[image]

How can I treat those statement as general statement? Thanks for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you're trying to include `file.ext` in your post. I don't think you need this. If you do, you must create a file named `file.ext` in `root/_includes`. But as I said, I don't think you need this file as the docs are simply telling you how to include a file of any extension in a post. Just remove `{% include file.ext %}` from you post.

Comment: thanks, i have fix this issue, in the beginning, i think this label won't effective in markdown syntax, while it take effect.